# how to use loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout properly when testing server failover at client side

Tags: mysql, c3p0, mysql-connector, apache-commons-dbcp, connector-j

I am using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.30 to achieve quick failover when master goes down suddenly when a transaction is going on.

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.102.22,192.168.102.23/db?autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;loadBalanceStrategy=random&amp;profileSQL=true&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true&amp;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=10000" />
```

I have tried to specify blacklistTimout to 10 seconds.

```
loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=10000
```

Is the property being used in current scenario (please check driver, connection URL) **OR** I need to specify different URL prefix instead of **jdbc:mysql://** ?

Please correct me If I am missing any mandatory parameters.

Cheers,
Parimal

Answer (score 1):

Did you put in the port behind the ip? In this case for example port 7000

jdbc:mysql://192.168.102.22:7000,192.168.102.23:7000/db?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&loadBalanceStrategy=random&profileSQL=true&allowMasterDownConnections=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=10000"

Comment: In above case port is taken by default 3306 hence no need to specify it explicitly.